# Como otimizar o calculo de parcelas em valores "quebrados"

Tags: php, algoritmo

Possuo uma aplicação que, dependo do formato da parcela que o usuário selecione, o sistema retornará a quantidade daquela parcela. Por exemplo: Supondo um pedido de R$ 50.000,00 em duas vezes, o sistema guardará no banco dois registros contendo R$ 25.000,00.

O problema está na hora de calcular um valor "quebrado". Por exemplo: O usuário gera um pedido de R$ 100.000,00 e parcela ele tem três vezes, o sistema guardará **três resultados de R$ 33.333,33**.

O problema está na hora de obter o valor resultante, pois se eu sei que o valor da parcela foi 3 e multiplico o valor R$ 33.333,33 **obtenho R$ 99.999,99**, ou seja, esse `1 centavo` acaba faltando o que lá na frente gera um valor discrepante na hora de obter determinados relatórios.

Percebi que sistemas de notas fiscais fazem isso com perfeição...

**Como posso gerar parcelas (na maioria quebradas), contendo um centavo a mais quando necessário?**

Comment: Não sei qual foi a sua dificuldade, fiz um teste aqui informando o valor `100.000,00` sem o ponto e a a virgula, e na multiplicação obtive o valor exato. Você poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249208/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem mais de uma estratégia, mas quase todas se baseiam na acumulação de erro e desconto ao final.

Numa versão bem simples da implementação, você calcula o valor da parcela e subtrai de `parcela * (n - 1)` para saber a última.

Exemplo:

```
 valor = 10.000
 num_parcelas = 3
 valor_parcela = 3333,33

 ultima_parcela = valor - valor_parcela * (num_parcelas - 1)
```

Ou seja:

```
 ultima_parcela = 10.000 - 3333,33 * (3 - 1)
```

Resultando em:

```
 3333,34
```

Tem muitas outras maneiras de fazer, algumas pouco complexas, outras mais.

Se quiser "incrementar" o algoritmo, pode pegar a diferença de centavos das parcelas e ir "distribuindo" nas outras para que não se acumule tudo na última (no caso de dar diferença de mais de um centavo).

Outra idéia é fazer um `if` que, no caso do valor ser mais alto, colocar como primeira parcela, e se for menor, no final, assim o pagador tem sempre a sensação do valor "cair" ao final. Tem que ver o que é melhor no seu caso específico.

De qualquer maneira, para a maioria das estratégias, a fórmula acima é um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: Só um detalhe, que acho digno morar em comentário: se for fazer a divisão arredondando para baixo de `n` parcelas, o resto máximo é de `n-1` centavos. Você pode obter esse resto assim `((valor*100)%parcelas)/100` (ou encontrar outra fórmula mais direta)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que cabe numa elaboração da resposta mesmo. Se for o caso, com mais tempo, faço em código PHP mesmo, e levarei em consideração seu comment (pode deixar ele aí pra eu não esquecer :) )

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Irei implementar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Registre no banco de dados 3 casas decimais, depois utilize a função `number_format` para arredondar para 2 casas decimais quando recuperar os valores do banco de dados antes de somar.

Execute esse exemplo e veja:

```
$parcela = 33333.333;
echo number_format($parcela * 3, 2, ',', '');
```

Lembrando que uma divisão por padrão no PHP retorna mais que 2 casas decimais, apenas configure com number_format antes de gravar no database:

```
$total = 100000;
$totalParaGuardar = number_format($total / 3, 3, '.', '');
```

Comment: Poderia melhorar sua resposta [editando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/249214/edit) ela e colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Desculpe-me @SamuelFontebasso acabei editando junto de você

Comment: Agora está OK :)

Comment: Muito bem, assim sua resposta não entra na fila de *Publicações de baixa qualidade*.

Comment: Eu não sabia dessa fila, vou pesquisar. Obrigado!!